# UltraGrid Child Bands

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I would like to move the child bands of a master band to the very left when exporting to excel using ExcelExporter.

Right now, all the child bands are displaced one column to the right.

Also, each child band has a blank row above and below it. I would like to remove them as well.

is this possible?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub UltraGridExcelExporter1_BeginExport(sender As System.Object, e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.BeginExportEventArgs) Handles UltraGridExcelExporter1.BeginExport
    DirectCast(sender, UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.UltraGridExcelExporter).BandSpacing = UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.BandSpacing.None

    For Each band As UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand In e.Layout.Bands
        band.Indentation = 0
    Next

End Sub
```